# Use the Artifactory Plugin in Jenkins to conditionally download files from artifactory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

How can I choose a different download spec for the Jenkins Artifactory plugin based on the value of a build job string parameter?

For a given value of the string parameter I want to download a folder from artifactory, and for a different value of the string parameter I want to download a different folder from artifactory.

I'm trying to get these folders directly from artifactory because they contain build output from a different project that my build needs to use and change frequently, I can't just check them into the SCM for my build, but must have the current versions at build time.

I've looked at the pages for the [Jenkins Artifactory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) and at the [Jfrog Artifactory user guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF) but I haven't found anything on how to do this using the plugin.

I'm using a freestyle build with the Generic-Artifactory Integration option.

Jenkins version: 1.651.3
Artifactory Plugin Version: 2.8.1
Artifactory Version 4.6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use environment variables in both the spec path and the spec content.

In your case, you can upload to your SCM a spec for each job with the job name in the path. Then, you can dynamically set the spec file path using environment variable as shown below:
[image: specFilePath]

Another way is to set a variable (for example PATTERN-PATH) in each job and use it in the spec.

```
{
  "pattern": "libs-snapshot-local/${PATTERN-PATH}/*",
  "target": "out/downloaded/"
}
```

Comment: how do u set a variable? I use the String parameter, it seems it doesn't work for the spec.

Comment: I am using "This project is parameterized" > "String Parameter". 
Just retried this and it works fine. 
What version of the plugin are you using? 
Are you using "freestyle build" or "Pipeline script"? 
Do you see in the logs the variable same as in the configuration -  ${YOUR_VARIABLE}?

Comment: Yes, I use freestyle and latest plugin and latest jenkins mostly. Nothing in the log. If I echo it in shell, yes it is replaced.